# populate multiple instances of the same #DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table that's generated using PHP.

as the table is populating from the php output, it generates several instances of this:

```
<td>
<div id="costSpin">  
   <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br>
</div> 
</td>
```

I utilize this `costSpin` div anytime someone updates something on the page - they see a little spinner as the cost refreshes.

When the calls the script to refresh pricing, this gets actioned:

```
$("#costSpin").load("spinner.html");

   $.ajax({
      //code to refresh...
   });
```

Sweet.  This works.  My only issue with this is that if the ultimate table has 10 rows, *only that FIRST row shows the spinner.*

```
<td>
<div id="costSpin">  
   <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br> <!-- spinner works -->
</div> 
</td><td>
<div id="costSpin">  
   <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br> <!-- spinner doesn't work -->
</div> 
</td><td>
<div id="costSpin">  
   <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br> <!-- spinner doesn't work -->
</div> 
</td><td>
<div id="costSpin">  
   <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br> <!-- spinner doesn't work -->
</div> 
</td>
```

I *assume* that's because a `<div>` can only be used once?  I'm not sure what's causing this.  I was hoping I could get the spinner to load into EACH of the `<div>`s.  What am I doing wrong?

## Update

Since populating tables with PHP is a pretty common thing, in the event that this helps anyone else, here's the final code I used:

$x is a unique identifier that grows with each row that's created....

```
<div class="costSpin<?= $x ?>">
```

here's the code that calls the JavaScript function:

```
<select style="width: 230px" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" datax="<?= $x ?>" onChange="selectCustomerCMR(this)">
```

and the script itself:

```
var x = select.getAttribute("datax");
$(".costSpin" + x).load("spinner.html");
```

This all ensures that each instance of the class still has a unique name, so they end up being

```
costSpin1
costSpin2
costSpin3
costSpin4
```

Then, anytime the spinner is loaded, only that specific line's costSpin div is actioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid as `id` must be unique within the page. Remove the `id` and use a common class instead:

```
<td>
    <div class="costSpin">  
       <strong><? = $cost ?></strong><br>
    </div> 
</td>
```

Then amend your selector:

```
$(".costSpin").load("spinner.html");
```